# Is it possible to get full control of a user's account, no matter their role in the server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to build a bot that helps people stay focused when they want to study. My exam is coming up, and personally, I've been struggling with staying out of Voice Channels in my server. Is it possible to gain full control of a user's account, regardless of their ranking/authority in the server? Let's say I've been in a vc for too long and my time limit is up, I want my bot to have the authority to kick me out of vcs even though I'm like an admin or the owner of the server and my role as an admin is above that bot in said server. Would that be possible? To like give it an authority over my account or something like that? With permission from the user first of course.

Comment: The bot has to be above all the roles you want to have control of.

Comment: The question you are asking might be something that can be implemented in software but it is not about software development directly. If you disagree please show us what you have tried so far, in code!

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. Just an idea.

Comment: @Dominik ah man. Sad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, people with roles who are on the same, or even higher hierarchy level than your bot can't be kicked out of voice-channels by it. Thats just how Discord works, and there's no way around that.

---

However you can still notify the user, because you **can** track them, no matter what their rank is.
The [Event Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#event-reference) is what you're looking for in that case. For example, with the help of the [`on_voice_state_update` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) you can check, when a user joins a vc start a timer and after the timout notify him to disconnect and start studying. You will need the `Intents.voice_states` intent for this to work though.

---

It could look something like this

```
import asyncio 

async def checkUserTimeout(user):
    await asyncio.sleep(100) # 100 second timeout
    if user.voice.channel != None:
        print("user is in VC for too long")
        # do rest of what you want. Maybe kick members which the bot *can* kick?

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel != None:
        client.loop.create_task(checkUserTimeout(user))
```

Basically what this does is start a task whenever a user joins a vc, and if the user still is in a vc after a certain amount of seconds *(here: 100)* run some code.

Comment: AHhh oh no, I appreciate you letting me know that I can't gain authority over an account but I actually wanted to write the code myself to challenge myself XD. It's cool though, thanks! I appreciate the help